# RegEx to span newlines

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a text file from which I'm trying to pull names and birth dates using a RegEx. The wall I've hit as of now is that the strings can span multiple lines and my RegEx is not able to grab them all. The format of the data I want is always:

> last name, middle name(sometimes), first name, f. DD-MM-YYYY

This is my RegEx:

```
if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line):
```

This doesn't get the below line break:

```
Smith, John,

f. 25-12-1990
```

or only first part of below:

```
Smith, John, f. 25-12-

1990

Smith, John, f. 25-

12-1990
```

Here's the full code:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

a_list = []

f = open("/Users/me/Desktop/scrape.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
txt = f.readlines()

for k, line in enumerate(txt):
    if re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line):
        a_list.append((k, line))
print(a_list)


#df1 = pd.DataFrame(a_list)
#df1.to_csv('C:/Users/me/Desktop/outputs.csv', index=False)

f.close()
```

Data example:
[image]

Comment: Does [`re.DOTALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) or [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) help?

Comment: Which line break do you mean? https://regex101.com/r/nTnkRl/1

Comment: I think you fail to explain your problem properly. Looking at the line of code you gave, the argument to `findall` is `line`. I'm assuming you loop through the file line-by-line and search each of them. How do you expect the regex to find something from another line it can't see? Maybe try to do: `re.findall(..., file.read())`

Comment: This is why a [mre] is critical

Comment: For example:
lastName, First Name Here,
f. 07-06-1935

Comment: @Jens `re.DOTALL` is relevant when using a `.` and `re.MULTILINE` is relevant when using `^` or `$`. I don't think it will help here...

Comment: @pam_param I meant to see the code before that line. I understand the pattern. As I explained before, it seems like you are searching each line separately. Is that the case?

Comment: @Tomerikoo That is the case yes. I understand that it works somewhat on regex101.com (great site btw ty!), but when I run it on my command line I see specific names that it doesn't pull.

Comment: It also seems like you just match one name with `\w+,`. Shouldn't it be: `\w+,\s*(\w+,)?\s*\w+,`? Also, do you really expect spaces inside the same number? Something like: `2 5 - 1 2 - 1 9 9 0`?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating the lines of the file and only passing each line at a time to `findall`. The regex can only work on what you give it so obviously it can't match something you didn't pass to it. You will have to search the whole file at once:

```py
import re

a_list = []

with open("/Users/me/Desktop/scrape.txt", encoding="utf8") as f:
    txt = f.read()

    print(re.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', txt)
```

Comment: Ah I understand now. That makes sense! But I need to run that enumerate function for later though. Every time I find a match to my regex pattern I will need to search between the matches for an email pattern. The nature of the task is to find all names, birthdates AND emails. But not all the names have emails you see.

Comment: You could either search them together with the same regex, or alternatively search the file again. I don't see how `enumerate` helps if your matches span multiple lines... Anyway as I said, a [mre] will help. In that case a **SMALL** example of the exact file you have

Answer (score 0):

Your regex seems to be working.
First, you can check it online here: https://regex101.com/r/yWrCig/1
It matches 3 cases.

As regarding your code, use it like:

```
res = regex.findall(r'\w+,\s*f\s*\.\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d\s*\d', line)
if res:
    ...
```

Where 'res' is the list of matched strings.